# How to implement logical operators using bitwise operators

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

How can the logical operators `||` and `&&` be implemented using only the bitwise operators `&`, `^`, `|`, `~`, `>>`, `<<` the logical operator `!`, and `+`? I've looked around on stack overflow and google for someone's previous answer or some assembly implementations but haven't found anything yet. I figure if no one has any solution I might just turn to an HDL and see what it synthesizes.

Comment: Is this a practical question, or are you just curious?  (Perhaps you're stranded on a desert island, and your compiler's `&&` and `||` operators got broken during the shipwreck...)

Comment: @SteveSummit Yep, just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can't be, although it would be tempting to suggest that `a && b` can be written as `!!a & !!b` and `a || b` as `!!a | !!b`.

This is because `||` and `&&` have a property where the evaluation of the second argument does not happen if the result of the expression is known from the result of the first argument. E.g. for `true || A`, `A` is not evaluated, and for `false && B`, `B` is not evaluated. So if you attempted to replicate either `||` or `&&` with bitwise operators, then you could well introduce side effects into your program.

Also `||` and `&&` are *sequencing points*, whereas the bitwise operators are not. So `a++ && a++` is defined for example, but `a++ & a++` is undefined.

Comment: To be fair, you could implement the shortcircuiting with multiple if/else statements and bitwise operators. It's gross but possible.

Comment: @yhyrcanus: Indeed, but that's outside the "only" constraint.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it gives a good semi-solution, but also understands that if you used `!!a & !!b` then an expression like `!!a & !!(b/a)` could produce errors while `a && (b/a)` would not.